# Database design - terminology query

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

This is a bit of a soft question but none the less valid for it I hope.

I'm designing a database that will need to hold parent-child information (as in actual parents and actual children, not the concept).

In recognition of non-traditional family setups I'm wondering what a good choice of terminology is now instead of the traditional "Mother" and "Father".

Something like "ParentGuardianOne" or "ParentGuardianTwo" with the second one nullable? Or will this cause problems down the line with an implied or inferred inferiority from ParentGuardianTwo?

If anyone's solved a similar problem I'd appreciate some input from them.

A news article on this [here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2011/01/07/AR2011010706741.html)

Comment: English.SE is the place for terminology requests, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a separate parentguardian table that stores many to many relationships.  There can be multiple parents per child and multiple chilren per parent. You should not store parent/guardian information directly in the children table.

Comment: Please reread the question. I'm looking for the appropriate _terminology_ not how how to design the table structure ;-)

Comment: But you needed design advice more than terminology. in a many to many relationship the terminology would be guardian as it is inclusive of both parents and guardians.  And you may have more than two because in a divorce and remarry situation, the step parents might also have a guardian relationship.  So the Junction table is the only realistic design.  You might even design it so that you put the specific relationshipship in the table such as the father, mother, aunt, step-parent, court_appointed guradian, etc.

Comment: If there's something in the question that has made you think that I needed design advice then that certainly wasn't my intention. I'm pretty clear on how to do that aspect of it (and FWIW it's pretty similar to what you've suggested). I was just looking for what I should _call_ them, regardless of where/how I choose to store them. I wasn't aware that guardian was a superset of parent; I'd always have thought of it as a person legally responsible for an incompetent person or someone legally responsible for a minor (in _loco parentis_).

Comment: A guardian is (are) the person (s) leagally responsible for a minor or a person deemed mentally incompetent. In most case the guardians of a child are the parents or some other relative. Sometimes the guardian is someone court-appointed if no relatives are available for one reason or another. I would view it as teh most general term available.  Of course it is possible to be parent who has lost the guardianship of a child. So it is not a perfect term.

Comment: I'm actually intrigued by one part of your comments. "You might even design it so that you put the specific relationship in the table such as the father...". Is this a common pattern that you see/use as junction tables for me, are well, just junction tables?

Comment: @noonand, it would only need to happen inteh case where you have specifc information about the relationship that doesn't handily fit into either of the two parent tables. For instance a person might be in here as the father of two children, the child of two other people and the leagal guardian of someone else.